# Equivalent characterization of essential (large) submodule

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I'm stuck with the following question in the sense that I admit I cannot come up with a decent solution. Here is the question:

We define a submodule $N$ of the $R$ module $M_R$ to be essential (large) in $M_R$ if, for any submodule $L\leq M_R$, $N\cap L=0$ implies $L=0$.

Then prove the following:

A submodule $N\leq M_R$ is essential in $M_R$ if and only if $\;\forall\; x\in M,\;x\neq 0$, there exists $r\in R$ such that $xr\in N$ and $xr\neq 0$.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you mean «...and $xr\neq0$.»

Comment: Next time *please* include whatever it is that you got (a non-decent solution?) in your question. The best way for us to help you unstuck yourself is to know *where* you got stuck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $N$ is essential in $M$ and let $x\in M$ be a non-zero element. Then the submodule $xR$ of $M$ is not-zero, so essentiality implies that $xR\cap N\neq0$. This means, precisely, that there is an $r\in R$ such that $xr\in N$ and $xr\neq0$.

Conversely, suppose $N$ is a submodule of $M$ which has that property and let $L\subseteq M$ be a non-zero submodule. If $x\in L$ is a non-zero element, by hypothesis there is an $r\in R$ such that $xr\in N$ and $xr\neq 0$. But then $0\neq xr\in N\cap xR\subseteq N\cap L$, so $N\cap L\neq0$. We thus see that $N$ is essential.

Comment: In the text I have i assure it is written $xr=0$ not $xr\neq 0$. However these are handouts given by my teacher so the text of the assignment may be wrong. I trust you Mariano, maybe that's why my solution didn't convince me... it was definitely wrong :)

Comment: @uforoboa, if it were «$xr=0$» the condition would hold for all submodules $N$, as you could take $r=0$. This would be wrong, as there do exist submodules of modules which are not essential (like direct summands, for example=

Comment: oh yes... didn't even think about that... by the way... thank you very much for your kindness. Regards.